# Vercel build error path /vercel/path0/node_modules/bufferutil

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, vite, vercel

When i try to deploy my project to vercel, i continuously get the following build error:

```
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.1 -> 9.8.1
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.1>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.8.1` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-14T17_56_19_586Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

Please can someone help, this is driving me crazy!

Ive tried doing as I'm told; running `npm install -g npm@9.8.1` but that doesn't help.
Ive also tried deleting and reinstalling node modules and package-json file with no luck.
I've also tried changing the environment variables and CI to false.